# Inside OnClickListener I cannot access a lot of things - how to approach?

Tags: java, android

Inside an OnClickListener I cannot access most variables "outside" of the scope, like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.Button01).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent mainApps = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                mainApps.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                List<ActivityInfo> activities = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainApps, 0);
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.sygic.drive/com.sygic/drive/.SygicDriveActivity");
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }

        });
```

in this example I need to get the PacketManager, and I cannot get it since I do not have the Context available inside the OnClickListener.

I could make a static reference outside, and use it inside, but is that correct? Seems odd to have to do that all the time?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Replace `this` in your code with `MyActivity.this` where MyActivity is the class name of your Activity subclass.

Explanation: You are creating an anonymous inner class when you use this part of your code: 
`new OnClickListener() {`
 Anonymous inner classes have a reference to the instance of the class they are created in. It looks like you are creating it inside an Activity subclass because findViewById is an Activity method. Activity's are a Context, so all you need to do is use the reference to it that you have automatically.

Comment: I've been googling for a while just to find "MyActivity.this".  It seems so simple now.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: What about accessing variables which give the error `Cannot refer to a non-final variable table inside an inner class defined in a different 
 method`?  I can't access those via `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: Those are local variables. If they don't change you can change their declaration to have final in them. If they do change, but before your inner class is defined, you can just define a final version right before. E.g.: final int myFinalErrorCode = errorCode. Otherwise you have to do something like make and set a member on the activity that you access or in the inner class.

Comment: I don't understand this behave, but It works as you said `Activity.this.doStg()` . Can you attatch here @LanceNanek some url with more detailed explanation please. Is it somehow related with reactive programming?

Comment: See the "ShadowTest.this" example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: doesnt work. i get an error saying that the activity is not an enclosed class

Comment: Hey jonney, post a question with your exact source code and we can fix it. You must have a static class, or some sort of other definition that doesn't have a reference to the outer class like inner classes do.

Comment: any solution to do the same but in `kotlin`, i mean i'm passing `MyActivity::class` but it isn't working saying `Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
KClass<VideoListActivity>`

Comment: okk, i just solved it by `this@VideoListActivity`, it's almost reverse..

Answer (score 11):

You could also implement the OnClickListener interface in your class and avoid the need for an anonymous inner class. Then you would set the on click listener like this:

`findViewById(R.id.Button01).setOnClickListener(this);`

If you have multiple buttons using one listener, you can use a switch statement with view.getId() (which corresponds to the view's id in R.id) to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you can do, you can create an inner class that implements the onClickListener and pass the necessary arguments into the constructor of the class.  I still don't find that the cleanest approach.  I usually just create another method to perform my action.  So in the onClick(View v) I would do something like this.

```
onClick(View v){doMyAction(myParams)}

private void doMyAction(Object params){//do stuff}
```

And just pass the needed params from the listener method to the method outside the listener.

Comment: Ok, weird taht you have to do that way, but I guess it works. =)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Intent constructor in use to Intent(context, classname) and use getApplicationContext() in your innerclass.  Solved my problem anyway.