# How to increment a Counter inside an OnClick View Event

Tags: android, sdk

I know this might sound very basic but here's my problem:

I have an onclickevent listener that's supposed to increment the counter indefinitely when it's clicked:

```
final int counter = 0;
myimageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter ++;
    }
});
```

The problem is that I can't seem to call the counter from inside the onclick event unless it's set to **final**. However since it's final I can no longer change its value either.

I tried placing the counter within the onclick event, i.e.:

```
myimageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int counter = 0;
        counter ++;
    }
});
```

However, clicking it also resets the counter back to zero.

How do I solve this? I want to continuously increment the counter each time I click it,
but I can't define the counter outside of the onclick unless it's final, which means I can no longer increment it. And I can't define the counter inside the onclick either since it will only reset its value each time I click it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inside OnClickListener I cannot access a lot of things - how to approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076037/inside-onclicklistener-i-cannot-access-a-lot-of-things-how-to-approach)

Answer (score 14):

Solved:

```
myimageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter ++;
    }
});
```

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it

Answer (score 1):

You could declare 'counter' outside the Activity's oncreate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int Counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.hey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            c.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (Counter >= 0) {
                Counter++;
                e.setText("you clicked Click me "+Counter +"number of times");
                e.setTextSize(15);
                e.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                e.setSingleLine();
            }
```