# Android Firestore - get next item in collection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a quiz app with Android through Firestore. I am able to get the collection of questions and load the first question however upon clicking the "next button" it says the list is empty or it's telling me that my counter cant change because it's declared **final**

I have tried only having the counter be in the onclick method([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112791/how-to-increment-a-counter-inside-an-onclick-view-event)) but then I can't load the first item in the list.

I don't think another forloop is the way to go but I could be wrong.

This probably sounds pretty basic but how can I iterate to the next item in the list of the collection?

any and all help is appreciated.

here is what I have so far.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

loadQuestionSet();
}


private void loadQuestionSet() 

        questionColRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String questionString = document.get("question").toString();
//                        questionTextTextView.setText(document.get("question").toString());

                        loadQuestion();

                        quizAnswerSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                loadQuestion();
                            }
                        });
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + questionList);

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: was not able to get a list of questions for Quiz activity");
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "loadQuestionSet: " + questionList);

}

 private void loadQuestion() {
        // get next question in query
        //update score
        Log.d(TAG, "loadQuestion: " + questionList.toString());
        mCounter ++;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the query cursors as below.

```
    Query first = db.collection("restaurants")
    .orderBy("rating")
    .limit(25);

    first.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {

        DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                .get(documentSnapshots.size() -1);

        Query next = db.collection("restaurants")
                .orderBy("rating")
                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(25);

       }
  });
```

Comment: this is supposed to return 20 documents and then allow me to iterate through 20 of them right? if thats the case, for some reason its only letting me get through 4 and then throws an out of bounds error