# Accessing program data from within onClick() inner class

Tags: java, android, events, onclick

i'm trying to access an EditText from an onClick() method within an onClickListener implementation for a button.  here's the code:

```
transmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //data validation
        ///////////////////////
        boolean valid = true;
        if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString() == "") {
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Driver ID!";
            showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
            valid = false;
        }
        Log.e("smsDRVERR",((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
        //begin transmission
        ///////////////////////
        if(valid) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_TX_PROGRESS);
            Thread t = new Thread(txRunnable);
            t.start();
        } else {
            //do things if needed

        }
    }
});
```

the Log.e is never called (does not show up in logcat).  and the program executes as if the conditional statement doesn't exist.  how do i reference layout items properly in an onClick implementation?  i've also tried the following line:

```
Log.e("smsDRVERR",((EditText)smsActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
```

which was alluded to in this question i found on SO:

[Inside OnClickListener I cannot access a lot of things - how to approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076037/inside-onclicklistener-i-cannot-access-a-lot-of-things-how-to-approach)

but it does not solve the problem.  i'm missing something that i need to reference these items within this inner class, or maybe i have my syntax a bit jarbled.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your log statement is outside of the conditional; it should log unconditionally, with respect to the code.  Something's wrong with your logging or how you are looking at it.  Try a simple Log.e("a", "b"); at the very beginning of the method; once it's working, you can diagnose what else may be wrong.

Comment: the log statement isn't the problem and it works with different data.  this was a test i used before posting to make sure i could circumvent responses like this...

Comment: Above you "write Log.e is not called". Now you say "the log statement is no problem". Please provide accurate information and try to reduce the code to the minimum to reproduce your issue.

Comment: in other words, if i change the Log statement to: Log.e("A", "B"); as suggested above, the log shows up in logcat exactly as it should.  however, with the function call above, the program acts as though the Log is never called.  there is no error, and the logging does not show up at all in logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing your `String` correctly.

```
if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString() == "") {
```

is checking if the *objects* are equal, whereas you want to check if the *values* are equal.  You should be using:

```
if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
```

Personally, I'd assign the value returned by `getText` to a `String` variable, rather than calling `getText` multiple times:

```
String myEditTextValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString();
...
if ("".equals(myEditTextValue)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

First, is your onClick method being called? Second, don't use `==` to do string comparisons; use `.equals()`. (Strings that are equal are not necessarily the same object, which is what `==` tests.)

Comment: this was, indeed, the actual problem.  the reason that the Log.e() call wasn't working is because the function was being passed a null value.  thanks for the response.