# Error on the Android Intent Service

Tags: android, service, intentservice

Hello i have a Problem with my Code.I want to play the Music in the Background and this will function with the `IntentService` of Android.
But my SDk give me a Error if I implement the line.

Radio.java

```
public class Radio extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener, MusicFocusable, ViewFactory {
```

....

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View btn) {
            if (!playState) {
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);

                 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                "Here is Error 1"

            }
            else {
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                status.setText("Drücke Play!");
                handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);

                stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                 "Here is Error 2"

            }
        }
```

and

MyService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();
}
}
```

if you need more code just say it!

Comment: post the error and related logcats to start

Answer (score 6):

The error is because you are using `this` in an `onClickListener`, and you have to use `ClassName.this` in there. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077804/2581872) answer, it is because:

> You are creating an anonymous inner class when you use
>   this part of your code: new OnClickListener() {

Which means that the class you are referencing is no longer `this`, so to access/identify the class you have to use the class name. So you should use this:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View btn) {
        if (!playState) {
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
            handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);

             startService(new Intent(Radio.this, MyService.class));
        }
        else {
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            status.setText("Drücke Play!");
            handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);

            stopService(new Intent(Radio.this, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could use `btn.getContext()` instead of the `Classname.this` to make the code easier to copy to other classes. That would look like this:

```
startService(new Intent(btn.getContext(), MyService.class));
```