# OnClick not working in Fragment with radiobuttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I have a problem with `onClickListener` Can someone help?

```
Error:
10-16 04:30:50.489 921-921/adil.fragments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                
at adil.fragments.Fragment1$1.onClick(Fragment1.java:56)                                                               
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)                                                               
at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)                                                               
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)                                                               
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)                                                               
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                                                               
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)                                                               
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                               
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)                                                               
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fragment1.java;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate ...
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,  container, false);
    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    final Button radioButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    final Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);

    radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
                    button.setText("asd");
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

Main_Activity.java;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fragment frag1 = new Fragment1();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frgmCont,frag1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change**

```
final Button radioButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

**change**

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
                    button.setText("asd");
            }
        }
```

Move the above code to **onCreateView()** method

Answer (score 1):

i think you should move your onActivitycreated code to onCreateview as done in this code .

```
 Fragment1.java
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.TextView;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

RadioButton radioButton=null;
TextView textView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup viewGroup,Bundle bundle){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,viewGroup,false);
    radioButton=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
    textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("text changed");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     FragmentTrasacation        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameid,new Fragment1());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related question here:

[Inside OnClickListener I cannot access a lot of things - how to approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076037/inside-onclicklistener-i-cannot-access-a-lot-of-things-how-to-approach)

Most likely the error came from here:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
```

Because getActivity() inside onClick may not return the view you are intending it to return. Either get the pointer to the view in a variable where your radiobutton is located or put the value of getActivity() before onClick() in some variable before using it inside onClick.