# How to pass 'this' to class for creating dynamically Views?

Tags: android, android-view

in my Project,i have a class for creating dynamically Views like TextViews but i want click in views via `setonCLickListner` but this parameters is nat valid(this,Activity and Activity.getApplicationContext )

My Code :

```
public a(Activity context , List<Arr> myarraylist){

       for (Array w : myarraylist) {

                    TextView textView = new TextView(context);

                    textView.setText(w.getW_text());
                    textView.setId(w.getW_id());
                    textView.setTag(w.getW_id());
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


                    textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context.getApplicationContext());

                    //  textView.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
                }
}
```

I got error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

and my problem is how to pass this object to java class and after click in anyview ,return value to activity in onClickListner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
        TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(2);

        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ddff"));



    }
```

Comment: try using YourActivityName.this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inside OnClickListener I cannot access a lot of things - how to approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076037/inside-onclicklistener-i-cannot-access-a-lot-of-things-how-to-approach)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context.getApplicationContext());` with `textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);`